# C# MVC, partial renders as new page not inside div

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

There is already a lot of similar answers, but I didn't find solution for me. Thats why here is my situation.

When I return partial it returns as a new page not inside div.

Thet's how looks my controller action.

```
    public ActionResult AddNewDutyTime(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            return PartialView("_DutyTimeView", TimesheetHoursPageHelper.AddNewDutyTime(id));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

---

Below is a action link

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"Add Duty",
"AddNewDutyTime",
"Timesheets",
new {Model[i].Id},
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = dutyTimeId,
    OnSuccess = "$('#btnAddDuty" + Model[i].Id + "').prop('disabled', false)"
},
new
{
    id = "btnAddDuty" + Model[i].Id,
    area = "Client",
    @class = "btn btn-primary",
    onclick = "$('#btnAddDuty" + Model[i].Id + "').prop('disabled', true)"
})
```

---

here is div to update

```
<div id="@dutyTimeId" class="col-lg-12 top10">
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("_DutyTimeView", Model[i].DutyTimes); }
</div>
```

---

No errors in console, and unobtrosive.js is present. [chrome dev tools](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=FIKcaUWJPgXgQqroXMnzU1gYYvSWkC)

Before click on action link [link](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=tKtcFrqP9fcyBE9XInDJN8CSZautF0)

and after click [link](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=3PgAfa0HnIoShlqWNROUB0PrrlXSo1)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `_DutyTimeView` is partial page and contains no layout page?

Comment: @Lali, I am positive, it is a partial, and no layout, only model.

Comment: If its redirecting, the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loaded correctly, or you have other code interfering. Suggest you load the non-minified version and put a break-point on it to check its getting hit. In any case, its easier to just use the `$.ajax()` methods anyway (and the `@Ajax.ActionLink()` and `@Ajax.BeginForm()` methods are no longer being supported in core-mvc)

Comment: Can you try setting it as a GET request, so you don't have to submit your entire form?

Comment: And just noticed I linked you to the code to do that in your last question.

Comment: why do you add @ before Id `id="@dutyTimeId"`

Comment: @AhmedRagheb, it is a variable and in div I don't have outer scope @{}, and in action link I've already have this @ symbol

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks $.ajax() helped, but still I wondered why it happened, cause yesterday it was working perfect...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i have just install `jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` from nuget from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) this'll add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` to script folder i just reference it and that's it all's working fine.

My MVC version is `5.0.0.0` for other version please find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_16) link to download `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`

Also, make sure that unobtrusive JavaScript is enabled in your web.config (it should be by default).

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Just checked, have this option enabled in config. I don't know what affected my code that I have such issue... cause yesterday it worked perfect.

Comment: Ohh than check `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` is still there in browser's source becasue it seems like this is an issue just because of js and check your console as well if there is any error ?